# How do I structure components correctly in a Vue project?

Tags: vue.js

According to the " Vue " documentation : Component name should start with the highest-level (often most general) words and end with descriptive modifying words.

That is, I have, for example, a User page with several sections, About, Content, Posts.
And as a result, the components come out like this :

```html
User
  -- UserSectionAbout.vue
  -- UserSectionContent.vue
  -- UserSectionPosts.vue
```

And there is one problem. This is a situation in which it becomes necessary to create a common component for all these sections, let's say that they must have some kind of header. And actually, logically, it should be called SectionHeader, because it is a header that belongs to the section, but the result is confusion in the structure.

```html
User
  -- UserSectionAbout.vue
  -- UserSectionContent.vue
  -- UserSectionHeader.vue
  -- UserSectionPosts.vue
```

And at first glance, it becomes not very clear where the components of individual sections are, and where the subcomponents for the section are, because it will not be clear from the start that the SectionHeader is not a section called "Header", but a header for the section.

How can we restructure all this so that we don't get too far away from the vue's recommendations, and the visual perception becomes more obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Well as you said, the naming should go from the highest level to lower leveled words. In this case, *SectionHeader* would be the general descriptor and then *User* to describe that it is a section header only for the User page

So it would look something like this

```html
User
  -- UserSectionAbout.vue
  -- UserSectionContent.vue
  -- UserSectionPosts.vue
  -- SectionHeaderUser.vue
```